# Moving strings that contain HTML tag to resource files

Tags: c#, html, resources, internationalization

I wish to move some of the UI strings into the resource files. The strings contain some of the styling tags, for example :- "I wish to move this `< i >string< / i >` into resource files."

What is the best way to do this? If possible, please give an example with the code?

PS :- 1) Breaking up the string in 3 parts is not an option, as it makes translation tough.

2) I tried using :- `@string.Format(Resources.ResourceString, string)`.
Where `ResourceString` = I wish to move this `< i >{0}< / i >` into resource files.

Comment: What kind of technology are you talking about? C#? ObjC? Java? Something else?

Comment: C#...i also tried using, @html.raw(string.Format(Resources.ResourceString, string)), Where ResourceString = I wish to move this < i >{0}< / i >. It works fine, but i wish to know if its the best method?

Comment: U could use Html.Raw, however I wouldn't put logic in the resource file. Using Raw could make me insert JavaScript in the resources I guess. Why can't you just put the string only in the resource file? Why would you need html tags in there?

Comment: I wish to provide some styling tags to the strings that i am moving into the resource files. Thus i would need html tags to be part of those stings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite common to include HTML formatting in localizable string resources and translators (as well as the CAT tools that translators use) are generally knowledgeable about basic HTML and will keep your HTML tags in the translations. Although of course you should check that your localized strings are OK when you receive your translations and as part of your QA plans.

As you said, breaking up the strings can cause more problems for the translator than keeping them as they are with their HTML tags.